# Create Type based off of paramter type

Tags: typescript

I have a generic function that returns another function.

When typing it, it might have required keys. Those required keys are optional for the first functional, but required for the second function IF they are not provided in the first. IF they are provided in the first function, they are then optional in the second (for overwriting)

Below is what I have tried, but haven't been able to figure it out.

```js
function myFunc<T>(opts?: Partial<T>) {
  // this typing is wrong, but I don't know what it should be
  return (moreOpts: Omit<T, keyof typeof opts> & Partial<T>) => {
    // do stuff
  }
}

type TestType = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const test1 = myFunc<TestType>({ name: 'John Doe' }) // no error
test1() // error -- needs age

const test2 = myFunc<TestType>() // no error
test2({ name: 'John Doe', age: 23 }) // no error

const test3 = myFunc<TestType>({ name: 'John Doe', age: 23 }); // no error
test3({ name: 'Jane Doe' }) // no error

const test4 = myFunc<TestType>({ name: 'John Doe' }); // no error
test4({ name: 'Jane Doe' }) // error -- needs age

const test5 = myFunc<TestType>({ name: 'John Doe', age: 23 }); // no error
test5() // no error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do it using 3 function invocations (the first being the one to which you provide the initial generic type in order to establish the base type to validate against for the inner ones).

Visit the playground link to explore/experiment and see if it meets your needs (and to view the actual compiler error diagnostic messages and other IntelliSense features):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQNQwGxgBMs4UAeAFQD4AKASkQG8AoRRdKEFJcgMRgoAzlERoAHtjBEhiAAoYUsAlWp04AByhCA-AC5EA4VEYBeaszbsOaLj0S0AdM42KMAWyEGAouIj4QIjRyAGs0AE84YENBEQAaRDDI6JoxSTRpWTA0ADc0FEQdK2tEAG1NbX1EAHl3GCgqBKSomOMLADJ5RWV8cjkYCBDGxF8oFAxoUIiWo3jE6ZS1agBdYusDcq0vGrqGyiaF1pEOrqUYFX7B4dHxyebo2agD5MQaNWWzCyYAXwBuKz+LG+LBYUHCGjQrzQIko4Mhpks7DAHjQBhEKBgYAA5v92BgsajEGAQO4AEb5f6AlgQBAiRBwEDYFAARkQCNQmGweEIJCgZCo0KgsIhdHo-xpYDpmOyLLZ9MZ+WZtCYRJRBgA5AApOAACyQABE4Gh1QkhDAAF6E9VY9AZdWIb5ixAAemdRLgYhQKDILGlioYvxdbvy3oKAFow0S0GgZIh8WgQRK6QymQAmOUcrC4AjEUgUSiC4VoUXi2miP0odMIlP5VMBoPuz2h31gGV1lXI9xW7V6xCG40JeMGVMAZgdTtdjZDPupZflTLH7PQWe5ub5+cLcJLs8l5db+UX84PytVXY1PYNRpNcYJw7HjsDk7AHunKBbMpHJ873Yw2T7V-HR83WfJsZyTUQaxQAAWDNly5HNeX5AsYS3AMdylfdoLlSCoK-NVEC1XVL2NQCGxA1933yXCO3wrVf0hft7QfBtX0QCMoxjWR40TOdIIAVlgzlsx5PMBRQkU0PAxAKwE6sFRQPi8LPAiL3-Acb0JUdSKfF8vR9GT6x00CUCAA)

```ts
function createValidator<T>() {
  return <First extends Partial<T>>(opts?: First) => {
    return (...params: Exclude<keyof First, keyof T> extends never ?
      [opts?: Omit<T, keyof First> & Partial<Pick<T, Extract<keyof First, keyof T>>>]
      : [opts: Omit<T, keyof First> & Partial<Pick<T, Extract<keyof First, keyof T>>>]) => {};
  };
}

type TestType = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
};

const outer1 = createValidator<TestType>();
const inner1 = outer1({ name: 'John Doe', size: 'green' }); // no error
inner1(); // error -- needs age

const outer2 = createValidator<TestType>();
const inner2 = outer2(); // no error
inner2({ name: 'John Doe', age: 23 }); // no error

const outer3 = createValidator<TestType>();
const inner3 = outer3({ name: 'John Doe', age: 23 }); // no error
inner3({ name: 'Jane Doe' }); // no error

const outer4 = createValidator<TestType>();
const inner4 = outer4({ name: 'John Doe' }); // no error
inner4({ name: 'Jane Doe' }); // error -- needs age

const outer5 = createValidator<TestType>();
const inner5 = outer5({ name: 'John Doe', age: 23 }); // no error
inner5(); // no error
```

Comment: would be ideal without the 3rd function, but this definitely gets my unblocked, really appreciate it!

Comment: @JoeLissner I agree that it's less than ideal. It's possible to implement without the extra initial invocation to define the initial type, but IMO it would become much more verbose for the user of the function. There's an open issue related to this if you want to read to understand why: [ms/TS#10571](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10571).